# Apply some aligment on this two elements when the windows resizes - Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQXwYY), and two littles problems. If I resize the windows, when the width gets **`991px`**:

1) The **`search box`** goes down (I don't want this). I want that the search box keeps in the same aligment that the **`'select'`** until it gets large (when it gets large, it's ok)

2) The **`'pagination'`** keeps align in right, I want it centered.

I guess is something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
}
```

But I don't know which classes I need to apply. Some help?

Comment: This is pretty tricky, I'm looking for a solution but until then, here is a tag you can use to target the "Search" text:  label[for="filter-list"] {

And for the Search box, use this:  #filter-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target smaller screens you just have to use the appropriate classes. Instead of `col-md-` I used `col-sm-` and `col-xs-` that target smaller screens.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmzKYR

Bootstrap's documentation is your best friend: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Indeed is very helpful! Also check this: https://www.edx.org/course/introduction-bootstrap-tutorial-microsoft-dev203x-0 . It is an online course that may help you understand TB better.